# Getting preact useId issue in fullcalendar v6 angular

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar in angular 15 and get this error randomly on npm install.
I am also using bpmn which internally use preact.

```
[ERROR] preact/compat:345:9-10 - Error: export 'useId' (imported as 's') was not found in 'preact/hooks' (possible exports: useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useErrorBoundary, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState)
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] ./node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js:345:9-10 - Error: export 'useId' (imported as 's') was not found in 'preact/hooks' (possible exports: useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useErrorBoundary, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState)
```

Tried installing preact in package.json, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're using at least Preact v10.11.0, as that's when `useId` was added.

Comment: I am using preact v10.12.1, still getting this issue

Comment: If you were using 10.12.1 you wouldn't have the issue, as `useId` is exported in those versions. Double check the version that's being resolved to, keep in mind `node_modules/` can be nested. You may need to use [`resolutions`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)/[`overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) to force the correct version.